# How to add system app permissions in android app for intune integration

Tags: android, azure, android-permissions, intune

I need to integrate intune sdk to my android app. Doc is saying :

The Intune App SDK requires three Android system permissions on apps that integrate it:+

android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS (requested at runtime if required)

android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS

android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS

The Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) requires these permissions to perform brokered authentication. If these permissions are not granted to the app or are revoked by the user, authentication flows that require the broker (the Company Portal app) will be disabled.

How to add MANAGE_ACCOUNTS and USE_CREDENTIALS permissions in my android app, these are system app permissions?

Comment: only way to add system permission to your app (except using root) is to make it a part of the system (the ROM) pre-installed to the device.

Comment: Presumably, this SDK is designed for use by system apps, not ordinary apps.